# openssl create CA, server certificate, and client certificate

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use helm with tls so I followed https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/tiller_ssl.md I generated certificate authority and used it to generate clients and servers certificate using bellow

```
openssl genrsa -out ./ca.key.pem 4096
openssl req -key ca.key.pem -new -x509 -days 7300 -sha256 -out ca.cert.pem -subj /CN=www.domain.com -extensions v3_ca

openssl genrsa -out ./tiller.key.pem 4096 
openssl genrsa -out ./helm.key.pem 4096


openssl req -key tiller.key.pem -new -sha256 -out tiller.csr.pem  -subj /CN=www.domain.com/emailAddress=userid@domain.com
openssl req -key helm.key.pem -new -sha256 -out helm.csr.pem -subj /CN=www.domain.com/emailAddress=userid@domain.com

openssl x509 -req -CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -in tiller.csr.pem -out tiller.cert.pem -days 365
openssl x509 -req -CA ca.cert.pem -CAkey ca.key.pem -CAcreateserial -in helm.csr.pem -out helm.cert.pem  -days 365
```

I created a different tiller and helm certificate but I used different userid in `emailAddress=userid@domain.com` and installed both server certificates but when I use the client certificate against the server it's verified anyway any client certificate is working with any server certificate so how can I create client certificate to be specific to one server with out the need to use password protected keys.